# Book on finite p-groups

Tags: finite-groups, book-recommendation

I would like to see some more advanced stuff on finite p-groups but don't know where to start and which books would suit for that purpose  (so far I read Isaacs 'Algebra' and a fair amount of his 'Finite Group Theory').

Does it make sense to have a look at Berkovich 'Groups of prime power order' or is it more like an encyclopedia?

Thanks in advance !

Edit:
Does anyone know how I could get Susan McKay's notes on finite p-groups? Seems to be what I am looking for!

Comment: Sorry for my previous answer, for some reason I thought you had wrote finite simple groups instead f p-groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Susan McKay's book is available at a very reasonable price, but it probably ships from the UK, so it may take a while to get to you, depending on where you are. See http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~pjc/qmmn/ .  I own a copy, and while I have not read it all the way through, I have found it very useful.  However, I'd also recommend the relevant chapter of Gorenstein's *Finite Groups*, which covers Lie rings, which I believe McKay omits.  There is also Leedham-Green and McKay *The Structure of Groups of Prime Power Order*, but it presumes knowledge at the level of the smaller McKay book.  However, it is one volume to Berkovich's SIX.  Berkovich appears to be a very expensive set of books.